# I restarted for a Ubuntu update and I now have a command line when it boots. How do I get back to my desktop?

Tags: command-line, .desktop

[image: Picture]

I restarted it and now I have this issue. I have tried typing in alt+f7, but that doesn't work. How do I get my desktop back?

Comment: try typing your user name and password. then type startx. If that worked, let me know..

Answer (score 0):

It is maybe a problem with your grub.
If you want to start the desktop, enter your login and your password, then launch `startx`. But that will not solve your problem.

You have to check your grub config file:

`grep 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=\|GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=\|GRUB_TERMINAL=' /etc/default/grub`

You should get :

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
 #GRUB_TERMINAL=console`

If not make a copy of this file:

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak
```

And change it to get the values that I give you

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Update your grup :

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then reboot and it should work again.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if is mistake in posting a question or it is your misconception, but the right shortcut is `ctrl`+`alt`+`f7`. Try and post feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If its not a error due to a graphics or boot issue, you probably just need to reinstall the desktop and/or login manager by logging into that prompt and running:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Note for other Ubuntu setups you may to try different commands instead - e.g. for Xubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

Ubuntu gnome desktop

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

etc